# ImageView centerCrop overflows ImageView bounds?

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/card_image"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The image should fill the image with its rectangle and scale it keeping its aspect ratio. It works fine when I do not move the view:

[image]

But, when I move the view, the image is drawn outside of its bounds:

[image]

I am using this [library](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) to move the card.

**How do I prevent that the ImageView draws its image outside its bounds?**

Comment: [Similar issues](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/issues/98) were reported using Facebook's Fresco. I use the same library, but with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), and I have never had these issues. You could try that.

Comment: @AlexWalterbos What about https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader ? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I've never worked with that library, but from a quick glance Picasso looks a lot easier to work with while enabling you to make it complex if you'd like. As always, it'll depend on your usage of the library which is better for your project. My use case is a very easy 'get this image from this url, fit it in that view'.

Comment: If you could give an answer with some code sample I will accept und upvote your answer.

Comment: I will set a quick thing up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this library with [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso), something like the example below. I've modified the code you provided a bit to keep it familiar.

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp">

    <!-- Note that I've deleted a lot of properties from the ImageView -->
    <!-- This is because Picasso will do a lot of that for us -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:src="@drawable/card_image"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

When you've inflated the view, you can simply find the view using `findViewById`, as you'd usually do.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
// Here comes the Picasso bit
Picasso.with(getActivity()) // You have to provide a Context
       .load(R.drawable.card_image) // Can be a Uri, File or String path as well
       .into(imageView); // Use .into(ImageView view, Callback callback) to register a listener for the image loading.
```

This will simply put the image into the `ImageView` without modifying it. You can add `.centerCrop()`, `.fit()` (example below) and other nifty methods to edit the image to the container properties automatically. Since you use `centerCrop` in your example I won't go into those, but refer to the Picasso github page I provided at the top for futher documentation.

To centercrop or fit the image, you add the method between `load()` and `.into()`:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
           .load(R.drawable.card_image)
           .centerCrop()
           .fit()
           .into(imageView);
```

Another great feature of Picasso is how it deals with slow or non-successful loading: you can add placeholders and error resources:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
           .load(R.drawable.card_image)
           .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
           .error(R.drawable.error_image
           .into(imageView);
```

Good luck!